# Ruby on Rails: apply layout to hundreds of existing static pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iframe

**The problem:**
Recently I was asked to make a completely static site "dynamic" in Rails.
The static site has hundreds of pages, each contains links to others, and my task was to integrate the static site into a rails app.

**I tried:**

iframe. I put the static site under /public and load the site in an iframe on my regular rails page. It works but it is not an acceptable solution:

1. Hundreds of pages in an iframe is bad for SEO. They just cannot be included in my sitemap.xml and indexed by google.
2. User cannot access a static page by typing a url in the
   browser.
3. Since Google Analytics code is in the layout, it obviously cannot track the user behavior in the iframe on page.

Am I missing any rails gems/tricks that can handle this situation?

In Rails, what is the best way to handle a large number of static pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In Rails, what is the best way to handle a large number of static pages

To *not* have a large number of static pages.

Seriously, Rails is one of the most robust, dynamic and comprehensive application frameworks in existence, and you want to fill it with static pages?

You'll be best making a [basic `CMS`](https://hackhands.com/9-best-ruby-rails-content-management-systems-cms/) and populating it with [`markdown`](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/):

---

```
#app/models/page.rb
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
    #columns id | title | body | created_at | updated_at
    #has_many :categories -> the power of Rails; you can add whatever you want! 
end

#app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
class PagesController < ApplicationController
   before_action :find_page, only: [:show]

   def index
      @pages = Page.all
   end 
   def show
   end

   private

   def find_page
      @page = Page.find params[:id]
   end
end
```

This will give you the ability to create a simple set of routes:

```
#config/routes.rb
root to: "pages#index"
resources :pages, only: [:index, :show]
```

--

You'd have to populate the database yourself, or if you wanted to create a very simple admin area, I'd strongly recommend using [`Devise`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise):

```
#config/routes.rb
namespace :admin do
    root to: "pages#index"
    resources :pages, path: "" #-> yoururl.com/admin/...
end
```

This will give you the ability to create a [`CRUD`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) `admin/pages` controller:

```
#app/controllers/admin/pages_controller.rb
class PagesController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_page, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy]
   before_action :authenticate_user!

   def index
       @pages = Page.all
   end

   def edit
   end

   def update
      @page.update page_params
   end

   def destroy
      @page.destroy page_params
   end

   def show
   end

   private

   def page_params
     params.require(:page).permit(:title, :body)
   end

end
```

Then you just have to put your pages into the database, allowing you to call them through your routes. If you want custom routes, use [`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) to create them.

Answer (score 0):

I trust there is a solution idea can be like , converting all the static pages into CSV or Excel format document and after that getting data in a rails layout .

Comment: what about the links on the static pages?

Comment: This is why I said CSV or Excel .